# How to specify array of key value pairs for a generic object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create a generic solution for a type safe array of key value pairs

suppose we have a type like this:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}
```

I want to define `KeyValArr` type to have a type safe solution for usage below:

```
const myPersonKV: KeyValArr<Person> = [
  { key: 'name', value: 'john' },
  { key: 'age', value: 22 }
]
```

The solution I had on my mind was to define `KeyValArr` as below:

```
type KeyValArr<T> = {
  key: keyof T,
  value: T[keyof T]
}[]
```

but the problem with this approach is that the code below does not result in any error:

```
const tmp: KeyValArr<Person> = [
  { key: age, value: 'wrong type!' }
]
```

how can I define `KeyValArr` in a way to have type safety on `value` based on the defined `key`?

Comment: Like this `Person[]`?

Comment: Your examples have many typos and produce numerous TS errors. How can we help you if you don't take the time to give us accurate info?

Comment: @Inigo I'm sorry I had missed a `[]` on the `KeyValArr` type and edited it. Is there any other typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to define union type of allowed values upfront:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type Util<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: {
    key: Prop,
    value: T[Prop]
  }
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type Result = Values<Util<Person>>

const tmp: Array<Result> = [
  { key: ' age', value: 'wrong type!' }, // error,
  { key: 'name', value: 'wer' } // ok
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwBoCiSmriBXMgIwRt8AXwIFQkKAFVg9ADYAeACoA%20TDnZQA2jHjIwURlADWEEMgBmUZQF1qeQkVPnqeg8OdQAbiXk9uZV19MFstMVFxfEloADU-AMQVdSwgswtrOwBuKJioACUIRB55YA14-yLFWQVFOCQ0VVUogGM0WihgMjBqAEF4eBIQRULi0pSdLWwXEGoAcihOCDmWHwTuOYB3fWZO8AgAQgWRVYB6U6gEfXhPHBn50goVtcr5zYRjqHOoZBMCWyAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/callbacks), in my blog, you can find how to create similar data structures but with callbacks

Comment: This is a really smart solution. Thank you very much. I spent more than a day reading documentations and couldn't find a desirable solution. I believe the `MappedTypes` part of the typescript docs need to include smart examples like this.  Thanks again. Will definitely check out your blog <3

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type KeyValArr<T,K=keyof T>= (K extends keyof T ? {key: K, value:T[K]} : never)[]
const myPersonKV: KeyValArr<Person> = [
  { key: 'name', value: 'john' },
  { key: 'age', value: 22 },
  { key: 'age', value: '22 }//error
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAGnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgF9cuUJCgBpCCABqRADYBBePAA8AFSYTMAa2nIAZlHUA%20LAAptEAB7AIqACaIoekIeNQA-DleUJTKAA3BS4KdQBtCQBdQShKVAhAhABKcKjcAGM0aigSEDgkNAkZP2k5JRVVApRUE0wocNZsF2lKAHJiMjaA4PlQ9oArZAALVDaoQRYCZt8oNvYIbqCQzgAmVYmpnBaQdoWl3v659YmAelOEeGR4XHTcIA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this solution results in explicitly writing every single key as type argument for each item which is not desirable and repetitive (since we have the key in code). I was looking for an implicit general solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't require writing anything, `K` has a default value, you don't need to override it, the usage will be the same as you have now - `KeyValArr<Person>[]`

Comment: Oh now I understand. I didn't know about type defaults. This a concise solution and I really like it. Thank you. I think this is the best solution for my scenario. Would you polish it and match it with question (notice the KeyValArr is an array type. also the link is not working) so I set your answer as the accepted one?

Comment: @Amin_mmz you're welcome! I've updated the answer, have a look